# LandingPage Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

I'm programming a LandingPage in AmpScript and this code needs to declare the variables.

Variable `@csptecnologia` has not been set
Variable `@ts_statusmsg` has not been set
Variable `@errorcode` has not been set

Could someone help me with this issue?

```html
%%[
IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN

  /* check if lead already exists */
  SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Lead",
   "Id,Email",
   "Email", "=", RequestParameter("email")
   )
  
  /* get lead id if lead exists */
  IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) > 0 THEN 
  SET @leadId = Field(Row(@subscriberRows, 1), "Id")
  
  /* update existing lead */
  SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Lead", @leadId,
      "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
      "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
      "Company", RequestParameter("company")
     )
           
  ELSE
   /* create a new lead */
  SET @leadId = CreateSalesforceObject(
        "Lead", 4,
        "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
        "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
        "Company", RequestParameter("company"),
        "Email", RequestParameter("email")
       )       
   
  ENDIF       

/* add lead to a campaign*/  
SET @CampaignMember = CreateSalesforceObject("CampaignMember", 3,
     "CampaignId", "7011t0000009Cl1",
     "LeadId", @leadId,
     "Status", "Sent"
      )  
     
/* send a confirmation email */
var @csptecnologia.com
SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SET @ts_extkey = "17699"
SET @ts_email = "leopoldo.ribeiro@csptecnologia.com" RequestParameter('Email')
SET @ts_subkey = _subscriberkey

SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", @ts_extkey)
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)
 
SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @ts_email)
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @leadId)

AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)

SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)
  
]%% 
<h2>Thank you for submitting the form, you will get a confirmation email shortly.</h2>

%%[ ELSE ]%%

<table style="padding: 20px;"><tr><td>
      <h2>Please fill in the form:</h2>
      <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
         <label>First name: </label><input type="text" name="firstname" required=""><br>
         <label>Last name: </label><input type="text" name="lastname" required=""><br>
         <label>Company: </label><input type="text" name="company" required=""><br>
         <label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" required=""><br>
         <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>  
</td></tr></table>

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: your test address is still in line 47; `SET @ts_email = "leopoldo.ribeiro@csptecnologia.com" RequestParameter('Email')` - use either the literal email address _or_ `requestparameter('email')` - also you've declared your email domain as a variable in line 43, which probably can go after fixing 47 :)

Comment: You can't reference `_subscriberKey` after submitting the form.  You'll have to pass it as a hidden field in your form and retrieve it's value like your other form fields.